# init float array given increment with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

What would be the most effective way to
initialize a float array of size `n` given increment using linq
for instance if array increment is `0.05208` starting on `1.06771`

I would have

```
float[] x =  {1.06771, 1.11979, 1.17187, 1.22395}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.Range()`.  It produces a continuous range of integers given start and count arguments.

```
float[] x = Enumerable.Range(0, 4)
    .Select(n => 1.06771f + 0.05208f * n).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [`Range`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range(v=vs.100).aspx) method, like this:

```
var x = Enumerable.Range(0, n).Select(i => 1.06771f + 0.05208f * i).ToArray();
```

And as a fun exercise, you could also create your own [iterator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dscyy5s0.aspx) like this:

```
public IEnumerable<float> Sequence(float start, float step)
{
    while (true) {
        yield return start;
        start += step; 
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
var x = Sequence(1.06771f, 0.05208f).Take(n).ToArray();
```

<sup>*CAUTION*: Be aware that the `start += step` will cause round-off errors to accumulate as you iterate through your sequence.</sup>